# Exiting out of a function in Javascript. Simple rock, paper, scissors game

Tags: javascript

How do i stop the function from executing if the userChoice is null or a word apart from rock,paper or scissors. 
I've tried to use return but i couldn't get it to work. 
Any help is appreciated.
Thanks

JS Fiddle Link = http://jsfiddle.net/Renay/d9bea2ra/1/

```
var userChoice = prompt('Do you choose rock, paper or scissors?');
var compChoice = Math.random();

if (compChoice <= 0.34) {
    compChoice = 'rock';
} else if (compChoice <= 0.67) {
    compChoice = 'paper';
} else {
    compChoice = 'scissors';
}

function compare() {
    if (userChoice == compChoice) {
        console.log( 'The result is a tie!');
    } else if ((userChoice == 'rock' && compChoice == 'scissors') || (userChoice == 'paper' && compChoice == 'rock') || (userChoice == 'scissors' && compChoice == 'paper') ) {
        console.log( 'You win!');
    } else {
        console.log('You lose!');
    }

    if (userChoice === null) {
        console.log('Please select an option');     
    } else if (userChoice !== 'rock'&&'paper'&&'scissors') {
        console.log('Please select rock, paper or scissors');    
    }
}

console.log('Your choice = ' + userChoice);
console.log('Computer Choice = ' + compChoice);
compare();
```

Comment: Where do you want to exit the function? `return` should work.

Comment: In the if statement where userChoice === null and when userChoice !== 'rock'&&'paper'&&'scissors'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The condition in your `if` statement is wrong. It should be:

```
if (userChoice !== 'rock' && userChoice !== 'paper' && userChoice !== 'scissors')
```

An expression of the form `e1 && e2 && e3 && ...` evaluates to last `eN` sub-expression if all of them truthy. So your test was equivalent to:

```
if (userChoice !== 'scissors')
```

You should put that check *before* displaying the result of the game, and return from the function then. So it should be:

```
function compare() {
    if (userChoice === null) {
        console.log('Please select an option');    
        return; 
    } else if (userChoice !== 'rock' && userChoice !== 'paper' && userChoice !== 'scissors') {
        console.log('Please select rock, paper or scissors');   
        return; 
    }

    if (userChoice == compChoice) {
        console.log( 'The result is a tie!');
    } else if ((userChoice == 'rock' && compChoice == 'scissors') || (userChoice == 'paper' && compChoice == 'rock') || (userChoice == 'scissors' && compChoice == 'paper') ) {
        console.log( 'You win!');
    } else {
        console.log('You lose!');
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks for picking up that error. And yep i just moved my code around and it worked!  Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

Just do `return;`

```
function compare() {
  if(!userChoice)
     return;
  // (...) more code
}
```

A `return` call exits the function. But note that you can only use `return` inside a `function`

Answer (score 0):

If i understand correctly, you want to return to the beginning of the code. You should wrap the entire thing in a function, then call that function again:

```
function rockPaperScissors() {
    var userChoice = prompt('Do you choose rock, paper or scissors?');
    var compChoice = Math.random();

    if (compChoice <= 0.34) {
        compChoice = 'rock';
    } else if (compChoice <= 0.67) {
        compChoice = 'paper';
    } else {
        compChoice = 'scissors';
    }

    function compare() {
        if (userChoice == compChoice) {
            console.log( 'The result is a tie!');
        } else if ((userChoice == 'rock' && compChoice == 'scissors') || (userChoice == 'paper' && compChoice == 'rock') || (userChoice == 'scissors' && compChoice == 'paper') ) {
            console.log( 'You win!');
        } else {
            console.log('You lose!');
        }

        if (userChoice === null) {
            console.log('Please select an option');
            rockPaperScissors();
        } else if (userChoice !== 'rock' && userChoice !== 'paper' && userChoice !== 'scissors') { // fixed
            console.log('Please select rock, paper or scissors'); 
            rockPaperScissors();
        }
    }

    console.log('Your choice = ' + userChoice);
    console.log('Computer Choice = ' + compChoice);
    compare();
}
rockPaperScissors();
```

You also had an error with checking if it isn't one of rock, paper, or scissors, so i fixed that. ([It seems Barmar got to it before me](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26323790/3187556).)

Comment: I tried wrapping the entire thing in a function but it didn't execute the code for some reason. And thanks for helping with that error. Appreciate it.

Comment: Oh yeah, you need to call the function also. ;)

Comment: Oh ye, i missed the call at the end haha. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

I updated each **if/else** part of your function to exit when it match **if/else** condition with `return false`. In addition I changed the `if (userChoice === null)` check to  `if (userChoice === "")` because it looks like that `prompt('Do you choose rock, paper or scissors?');` returns an empty string when the user doesn't enter any value. [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jyrkim/d9bea2ra/4/) Also, I just updated the beginning of the function to work accordingly to **Barmar'**s suggestion (he got it right first time around).

```
function compare() {
    if (userChoice === "") {
        console.log('Please select an option');
        return false;
    } else if ((userChoice !== 'rock') && (userChoice !=='paper') && (userChoice !=='scissors')) {
        console.log('Please select rock, paper or scissors');
        return false;
    }

    if (userChoice == compChoice) {
        console.log('The result is a tie!');
        return false;
    } else if ((userChoice == 'rock' && compChoice == 'scissors') || (userChoice == 'paper' && compChoice == 'rock') || (userChoice == 'scissors' && compChoice == 'paper')) {
        console.log('You win!');
        return false;
    } else {
        console.log('You lose!');
        return false;
    }
}
```